# Reading multiple JSON Files from my own WebHosting server and constructing several <Div> structures in Html with the information read in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

My goal is to fill a product catalog in a website without just hard-coding it, In theory what I want is to have a directory filled with multiple JSON files (which each have the details of 1 product) and have Java script read all the files of the directory and construct a  that has the name, price,etc.

However I don't seem to be able to just grab the multiple JSON files that each has information like (name:xxx ,price:xxx )

I know that Template Literals is great to read a JSON file but for some bizarre reason all the tutorials have the JSON file typed in the javascript code itself so that it can just be referenced right there without "looking for it".

the directory I'm trying to read is inside the same server I have my website on, and in term It shouldn't be to hard right?.

Comment: Is the JavaScript running in the user's browser, or in a server side application?

Comment: Is running on the browser I think, I linked the script file via the <script> tag to the html website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery library and use the getJSON function to read the file from the server. The file will need to be in the same directory structure as the web page the JavaScript is running from.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

The JSON data from the file will then be available in a JavaScript object.

As getJSON points to a single file at a time, it might be better to have all of your products in a single JSON file.

Comment: Yeah! I could get the information just the way I wanted, and also yeah.... I was dreading the fact that I used multiple JSON files instead of a single one which I really don't know how to actually accomplish that

Answer (score 0):

For your multiple file JSON question, you can merge JSON files easily using PowerShell. The following of course assumes you have clean JSON.

If you have a files named ProductComputer, ProductPrinter, etc. that look something like this:

```
{
  "Name":"Laptop Computer",
  "ID" :125,
  "Status": "Inactive",
  "Price" :900.00
}
```

You could then run this in PowerShell to merge the files:

```
"[" + ((Get-Content product*.json -Raw) -join ","  ) + "]" | out-file AllProducts.json
```

If you would like to put the square brackets on their own lines, then add "`n" where needed:

```
"[`n" + ((Get-Content product*.json -Raw) -join ","  ) + "`n]" | out-file AllProducts.json
```

If you need to sort the products during the merge then:

```
$products = "[" + ((get-content json*.json -raw) -join ","  ) + "]"  | ConvertFrom-Json | sort ID
ConvertTo-JSON -InputObject $products.psobject.BaseObject | Out-File AllProducts.json
```